# Django edit form based on add form?

Tags: python, django, forms, logic

I've made a nice form, and a big complicated 'add' function for handling it. It starts like this...

```
def add(req):
    if req.method == 'POST':
        form = ArticleForm(req.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            article = form.save(commit=False)
            article.author = req.user
            # more processing ...
```

Now I don't really want to duplicate all that functionality in the `edit()` method, so I figured `edit` could use the exact same template, and maybe just add an `id` field to the form so the `add` function knew what it was editing. But there's a couple problems with this

1. Where would I set `article.id` in the `add` func? It would have to be after `form.save` because that's where the article gets created, but it would never even reach that, because the form is invalid due to unique constraints (unless the user edited everything). I can just remove the `is_valid` check, but then `form.save` fails instead.
2. If the form actually *is* invalid, the field I dynamically added in the edit function isn't preserved.

So how do I deal with this?

Answer (score 116, accepted):

If you are extending your form from a ModelForm, use the `instance` keyword argument. Here we pass either an existing `instance` or a new one, depending on whether we're editing or adding an existing article. In both cases the `author` field is set on the instance, so `commit=False` is not required. Note also that I'm assuming only the author may edit their own articles, hence the HttpResponseForbidden response.

```
from django.http import HttpResponseForbidden
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, redirect, render, reverse


@login_required
def edit(request, id=None, template_name='article_edit_template.html'):
    if id:
        article = get_object_or_404(Article, pk=id)
        if article.author != request.user:
            return HttpResponseForbidden()
    else:
        article = Article(author=request.user)

    form = ArticleForm(request.POST or None, instance=article)
    if request.POST and form.is_valid():
        form.save()

        # Save was successful, so redirect to another page
        redirect_url = reverse(article_save_success)
        return redirect(redirect_url)

    return render(request, template_name, {
        'form': form
    })
```

And in your `urls.py`:

```
(r'^article/new/$', views.edit, {}, 'article_new'),
(r'^article/edit/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.edit, {}, 'article_edit'),
```

The same `edit` view is used for both adds and edits, but only the edit url pattern passes an id to the view. To make this work well with your form you'll need to omit the `author` field from the form:

```
class ArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        exclude = ('author',)
```

Comment: Yes, it's a `ModelForm`. I needed `commit=False` for other reasons. An article is composed up of a whole bunch of stuff (including some m2m relations). I don't *think* it wanted to work with `instance`. I'll give this a try though.

Comment: In that case, I'd suggest putting the m2m relations (et al) saving/validation in the form instead of the view... either override the save method or possibly, look into formsets.  I guess it depends on the context of what you're working with...

Comment: Great and thorough example! Thanks! I learned more than the just the solution to this question.

Comment: Great Answer! I think its missing an example of the template action form tag. How could I know when to call article_new or article_edit in the template? Need to check form.instance.id ?

Comment: @DanielNaab I know this is very old but I'm so close to getting it working.. what do I set the form `action` attribute to? Would it be `r'^article/new/$'` or `r'^article/edit/(?P<id>\d+)/$'`? Thanks!

Comment: @stmyd Technically, you can just do `action="."`, because you want to post to the same URL you're rending the form from.

Comment: @DanielNaab: from django docs 1.5 on ward, I always use url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'). For your urls.py like (r'^article/new/$', views.edit, {}, 'article_new'), could you please advise what {} and  'article_new' represent? Secondly, is it correct that both new and edit action use the same template which is 'article_edit_template.html'? Thank you!

Comment: @learnJQueryUI: Those are the kwargs to pass into the view and the view name. All the parameters in the tuples (when not using the url() function) are passed as parameters to RegexURLPattern: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/urlresolvers.py#L201-L248

Comment: Great write-up, very helpful. A little thing missing from `urls.py`, namely the template to pass to the view function as an argument. Please consider updating with: `{ 'template_name' : 'article_new_template.html' }`

Answer (score 3):

You can have hidden ID field in form and for edit form it will be passed with the form for add form you can set it in req.POST e.g.

```
formData =  req.POST.copy()
formData['id'] = getNewID()
```

and pass that formData to form