# Django edit template for ModelForm is not being filled in with values

Tags: python, django, modelform, django-forms

---

I have a ModelForm that I have created a view and template with to add an instance to the database. I am now trying to extend this to be editable when the user clicks a button - but when they do that the form/template page appears and I get the "This Field is required message" but all fields are empty instead of pre-populated with the instance I passed in, but when I edit the values to something different than originally then in my database the correct instance is updated. So it is passing the primary key but none of the values are showing up. If anyone can tell what I am doing wrong I would appreciate it, oh, and I am using this post [Django edit form based on add form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854237/django-edit-form-based-on-add-form/1854453#1854453) as a basis so please don't just send me there.

Here are my files

**ModelForm**

```
class CreditCardForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = CreditCard
    fields = ('name_on_card','card_number','contact_number_on_card')
```

**View**

```
def edit(request, id=None, template_name='article_edit_template.html'):
if id:
    print "Edit Mode"
    card = get_object_or_404(CreditCard, pk=id)
    if card.card_owner != request.user:
        raise HttpResponseForbidden()
else:
    print "Create Mode"
    card = CreditCard(card_owner=request.user)

if request.POST:
    print "request.POST"
    form = CreditCardForm(request.POST, instance=card)
    if form.is_valid():
        print "is_valid()"
        form.save()

        # If the save was successful, redirect to another page
        # redirect_url = reverse(article_save_success)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/cards/')
else:
    print "else"
    form = CreditCardForm(instance=card)

return render_to_response(
    'create_credit.html', 
    {'form': form,},
    context_instance=RequestContext(request)
)
```

**Template**

```
{% include "base.html" %}

<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
<fieldset>
<legend>Required</legend>

<div class="fieldWrapper">
    {{ form.name_on_card.errors }}
    <label for="id_topic">Name as it appears on card:</label>
    {{ form.name_on_card }}
</div>
<div class="fieldWrapper">
    {{ form.card_number.errors }}
    <label for="id_topic">Last 6 digits of card number:</label>
    {{ form.card_number }}
</div>  
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
<legend>Optional</legend>
<!-- This is for Credit Card's Only -->
<div class="fieldWrapper">
    {{ form.contact_number_on_card.errors }}
    <label for="id_topic">Institution contact number: 1-</label>
    {{ form.contact_number_on_card }}
</div>
</fieldset>
<p><input type="submit" value="Save"></p>
</form>
```

**URLS**

```
    url(r'^new/credit/$', views.edit, {}, 'crds_newCredit'),
url(r'^edit/credit/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.edit, {}, 'crds_editCredit'),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@xizor use a link instead a button to redirect to the edition form, becasue with the button you are probably sending a post to the view.

PS: Please forgive my English, edit this answer if you think it is right to make it more useful.

Comment: Brilliant! That was it, I do not know much about this sort of thing - could you tell me why that was the case. Why is it that sending a POST does not work but the link does?

Comment: You can use a button too, but as a link, putting a javascript function in the button's onClick event to redirect the page to the edition form. But if you enclose the button in form tags and add the attribute acction='post' to this form, when you do a submit on that button, you will be sending a post message to the view.