# Edit/Add objects using the same django form

Tags: python, django

I already used the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854237/django-edit-form-based-on-add-form), but for some reason I'm not getting a good result.

I'm trying to use the same template for my edit form and my add form. Here's my `urls.py`:

```
url(r'^app/student/new/$', 'edit_student', {}, 'student_new'),
url(r'^app/student/edit/(?P<id>\d+)/$', 'edit_student', {}, 'student_edit'),
```

And my `views.py`:

```
def edit_student(request, id=None, template_name='student_edit_template.html'):
if id:
    t = "Edit"
    student = get_object_or_404(Student, pk=id)
    if student.teacher != request.user:
        raise HttpResponseForbidden()
else:
    t = "Add"
    student = Student(teacher=request.user)

if request.POST:
    form = StudentForm(request.POST, instance=student)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()

        # If the save was successful, redirect to another page
        redirect_url = reverse(student_save_success)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_url)

else:
    form = StudentForm(instance=student)

return render_to_response(template_name, {
    'form': form,
    't': t,
}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

And my `forms.py`:

```
class StudentForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Student
    exclude = ('teacher',)
```

And finally my template `student_edit_template.html`:

```
<h1>{{ t }} Student</h1>
<form action="/app/student/edit/{{ student.id }}" method="post"> {% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

For some reason, this is throwing a 404:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://192.168.1.3:5678/app/student/edit/
```

I'm probably missing something easy here, but at this point I need another set of eyes on it at the very least.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: One thing is: that URL needs to look like `http://192.168.1.3:5678/app/student/edit/789/` or somesuch -- there's no ID in your URL, hence the 404.

Comment: Right -- but you can see from the template that I'm posting to that student ID, it should be posting to that URL.

I should have been more specific -- it's 404'ing when I add a record. Is this something to do with the id not being generated yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting the 404 because `/student/edit/` requires an id at the tail end otherwise there's no route, and when you're coming from `/student/new/` you don't have an id yet.  Create a route and view for `/student/edit/` and put logic in there to handle the case for when you're creating a record on POST.

Comment: Yep - that was it. I wasn't passing `student` to the template, so `id` was never going to get populated in any case. I had to pass `student` then change my POST call to have a trailing slash. That did the trick.