# Add form returns None as record id, causing URL to error

Tags: django, django-views

I'm using the code found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854237/django-edit-form-based-on-add-form) (SO.com) to use the same template to both add and edit a record, but when I add a new record and click Submit, I get a 404 on the URL `http://192.168.1.3:5678/app/student/edit/None/`, and I'm not exactly sure why.

Here is the relevant portion of my `urls.py`:

```
    url(r'^app/lesson/new/$', 'edit_lesson', {}, 'lesson_new'),
url(r'^app/lesson/edit/(?P<id>\d+)/$', 'edit_lesson', {}, 'lesson_edit'),
```

Here is the relevant portion of my `views.py`:

```
def edit_lesson(request, id=None, template_name='lesson_edit_template.html'):
if id:
    t = "Edit"
    lesson = get_object_or_404(Lesson, pk=id)
    stu = get_object_or_404(Student, pk=sid)
    if stu.teacher != request.user:
        raise HttpResponseForbidden()
else:
    t = "Add"
    lesson = Lesson()

    if request.POST:
        form = LessonForm(request.POST, instance=lesson)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

            # If the save was successful, redirect to another page
            return view_lessons(request)

    else:
        form = LessonForm(instance=lesson)

    return render_to_response(template_name, {
        'form': form,
        't': t,
        'lesson': lesson,
            }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

And finally, here is my template:

```
<h1>{{ t }} Lesson</h1>
<form action="/app/lesson/edit/{{ lesson.id }}/" method="post"> {% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I'm certain that I'm missing something really easy, but I can't seem to put my finger on it. I'm using Django 1.3.1 if that makes any difference.

Thanks,
MC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to specify any URL in the form's `action` attribute. Just do

```
<form action="" method="post">
```

and it will POST back to the URL that you originally used to access it, which is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

In add case `{{ lesson.id }}` is None, because `lesson` is unsaved `Lesson()` instance, without pk, so your form is being fired to nonexistent URL.

I recommend separating create and edit views and processing them in different ways (or even inherit generic views - with new class-based generic views it's easy and pleasant).

Also, use `{% url %}` template tag everywhere instead of hard-coded urls.

Comment: Please don't separate the add and edit views, unless you have a good reason to do so. Needing to customize the form's action is *not* a good reason, since you can just leave it blank as @DanielRoseman explains to have it just do a postback.

Comment: It's not just about form action. In topicstarter's code there's different processing routine with `if id:...` for edit and add cases. There's event page title being set up in a view! Yes, he should repeat some stuff for POST processing for separate add and edit, but with generic views all that stuff goes away.