# Django editing user's posts

Tags: django

I am working in a blog application using django. A user can add posts and edit their own posts. However, I am having trouble with retrieving user's posts. Here is a similar question, but it does not work with my application: [Django edit form based on add form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854237/django-edit-form-based-on-add-form) Any help is truly appreciate

Here is my code:

```
@login_required
def edit(request, id):
    if id:
        post = get_object_or_404(BlogPost, id=id)
        if post.author != request.user:
            return render(request, "403.html")
        else:
            post = BlogPost(author=request.user)

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AddPost(request.POST, instance=post)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.save()
            messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS,
                                 'You have succesfully updated your post')
            return redirect('homepage')
    else:
        form = AddPost(instance=post)
    return render(request, 'blog/update.html', {'form': form})
```

Here is my model:

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(
        max_length=100, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=50).......
```

Comment: Your title implies that Django is editing your users' posts. Or is that a prepended tag, which should be removed? In any case, please edit to ask a more specific question in the title.

Comment: [HERE](http://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_start_project/README.html) there is a useful tutorial. It starts from the bases then it adds more difficulties. I remember that there is something like yours.. you have to search for.

Comment: I'm not sure what your actual question is. You say you are "having trouble" - what does that mean? What is actually wrong?

Comment: And I don't know if it's your problem (because I don't know what your problem actually is), but your first `else` clause looks like it should be one indent to the left: ie under `if id`, not `if post.author...`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Even If I a user is log in and try to edit a post that belongs to that particular user, it returns 403.html.

Comment: OK, fair enough. Can you post the BlogPost model?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I have added my model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `author` field is a CharField. I'm not sure what you're putting into that field, or how you're setting it, but it will never equal `request.user`, because that is an instance of your User model.

Normally the `author` field would be a ForeignKey to User, so that the comparison would be true for those posts authored by the current user. If you are putting the username into the `author` field, you could compare with that: `if post.author != request.user.username` - but I would really not recommend doing that, as you are breaking normalization for no good reason.

(Also note my other comment: your first else clause looks like it should be one indent to the left: ie under `if id`, not `if post.author...`.)

Comment: The author should be equal to the user's name. You are totally right about CharField, I do not need it