# How can i have both read only and editable fields in django administration?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-admin

I have a table which contains some information.

For example, I have two options like `View` and `Edit`. I will give `Edit` option for X info and `View` option for Y info on a table. I will make my options as a link so that I can able to click on the options.

Now, what I want to happen when I click on `Edit` is to display what Django admin normally has. When I click on `View`, I want info of that particular line to display as a non editable field.

I have already tried this but it is making both options read only fields.
Is this possible?

Comment: You have to pass instance of the model. For reference see [link reference ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854237/django-edit-form-based-on-add-form).

Comment: Post your admin code and the relevant parts of your models.